# Does apache storm do resource management job in the cluster by itslef?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, apache-storm

Well I am new to Apache Storm and after some search and read tutorials, I didn't get that how *fault tolerance*, *load balancing* and other resource manager duties takes place in Storm cluster? Should it be configured on top of YARN or it doest the resource management job itself? Does it have its HDFS part, or there should be an existing HDFS configured in a cluster first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Storm can manage its resources by itself *or* can run on top of YARN. If you have a shared cluster (ie, with other system like Hadoop, Spark, or Flink running), using YARN should be the better choice to avoid resource conflicts.

About HDFS: Storm is independent of HDFS. If you want to run in on top of HDFS, you need to setup HDFS by yourself. Furthermore, Storm provides Spouts/Bolt to access HDFS: https://storm.apache.org/documentation/storm-hdfs.html

Comment: A little relevant question:
If I don't want to run Storm on top of HDFS, does it do replication and other things managed by HDFS itself? (Does it have distributed filesystem of its own?)

Comment: Storm does not have an own distributed file system or distributed storage.